# Scrape/extract Youtube video information using youtube-dl

Tags: bash, youtube, youtube-dl

I want to scrape information from a YouTube playlist/channel (including Upload Date, Title, URL, Duration, View Count) using `youtube-dl` without downloading the videos.

There's a very useful example [here](https://archive.zhimingwang.org/blog/2014-11-05-list-youtube-playlist-with-youtube-dl.html) on how to use the `dump-json` switch together with `jq`, but it only output the URLs.

Basically, in the command line, how do I use the [keys](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#output-template) with `dump-json`?

Answer (score 2):

This command will dumb json data of the given link to terminal

```
youtube-dl -j 'link'
```

capture this into a file using

```
youtube-dl -j 'link' >> example_text.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Get Youtube playlist titles and urls:

```
youtube-dl --flat-playlist -j <playlist_link> | jq ".title, .url"
```

Get Youtube video title and duration:

```
youtube-dl --get-title --get-duration <video_link>
```